# ASP MVC DateTime validation error

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

In asp.net MVC 5, I have a form that displays data from a DTO object:

```
public class FieldDTO
{
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime StartFieldDate { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime StopFieldDate { get; set; }

    public String FieldName { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime StartJob { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime StopJob { get; set; }
}
```

In my controller class, I have:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
   var model = new FieldDTO();
   model.StartFieldDate = DateTime.Now;
   model.StopFieldDate = DateTime.Now;
   model.StartJob = DateTime.Now;
   model.StopJob = DateTime.Now;
   ...
   ...
}
```

In the view, I have:

```
<div class="col-md-10">
     @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StartFieldDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control datepicker" } })
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DataTurno, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
 </div>
```

And, I have the same razor code for the other `datetime` controller. I have added the `datepicker` class for jQuery UI DatePicker.

In the form, if I click on the "create" button, without modifying any controls, everything works.
When I change one of the last two `datetime` pickers and then click the "create" button, I get the validation error: `The field xxxx must be a date.`

I don't figure out what the problem is, because all the controls are generated the same way.

Comment: Where's your jQuery datepicker? It's most-likely because of your jQuery datepicker's date format.

Comment: Also, it's ok that on your View you have `EditorFor` for  `model.StartFieldDate` and `ValidationMessageFor` for `DataTurno`?

Answer (score 4):

There a number of potential issues.

Firstly the `[DataType(DataType.DateTime)]` and `[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]` attributes are only applicable when using `@Html.EditorFor()` and are used to render the browsers implementation of a HTML5 datepicker (it adds the `type="date"` attribute). Since you are using the jQueryUI datepicker, then those attributes are not required. In any case if you do want the browsers HTML5 datepicker, then the format needs to be `DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}"` (ISO format) in order to work correctly. Note also the HTML5 datepicker is only supported in modern browsers, and not yet at all in FireFox ([refer comparison](http://html5test.com/compare/browser/chrome-39/firefox-34/opera-24.html))

If you using the jQueryUI datepicker then it can be just

```c#
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.StartFieldDate, new { @class = "form-control datepicker" })
```

and set the format in the datepicker script

```js
$('.datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
```

The validation message could be from one of 2 issues. On the client side, `jquery-validate.js` validates a date using the `MM/dd/yyyy` format. You can override this to use `dd/MM/yyyy` by including [jquery globalize](https://github.com/jquery/globalize) or add the following script

```js
$.validator.addMethod('date', function (value, element) {
  if (this.optional(element)) {
    return true;
  }
  var valid = true;
  try {
    $.datepicker.parseDate('dd/mm/yy', value);
  }
  catch (err) {
    valid = false;
  }
  return valid;
});
$('.datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
```

The other potential problem is server side validation. If the server culture does not accept dates in the format `dd/MM/yyyy` (e.g. `<globalization culture="en-AU" uiCulture="en-AU"/>`) then a validation error could be thrown on the server, in which case you would need to create a custom `ModelBinder` for `DateTime`.

Side note: I assume `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.DataTurno, ..)` is a typo (the model your have shown does not include a property `DataTurno`) and that its really `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.StartFieldDate, ..)`

Answer (score 2):

because default format for date time is  mm/dd/yyyy. your date consider as a month then it gives error for that you need to add culture format.

```
        CultureInfo culture = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Clone();
        culture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "dd/MM/yyyy";

        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;
```

and in your js file in that you implement datepicker include code like

```
jQuery.validator.methods["date"] = function (value, element) { return true; }
```

i have same issue now works fine for me i hope it should help you.

Answer (score 1):

For me just have this code to ovewrite the default Jquery datetime validation:

```
$(function () {
   $.validator.methods.date = function (value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || moment(value, "L", true).isValid();
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like wrong **jQuery** datepicker's date format like @ataravati mention.

Try to init datepicker with the `dateFormat` option, like this:

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy' });
```

Get to debug or set the `dateFormat` option, after init, like this:

```
//this how to get what is it now
var dateFormat = $(".datepicker").datepicker("option", "dateFormat");
//set right format
$(".datepicker").datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "dd/mm/yyyy");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case this happens to anyone else.  I was originally having a validation error because my iOS app in swift was sending unix time.  I diagnosed that with a app.using block that read json from the request body.  Then, I changed the swift date to iso but it wouldn't work.  I spent several hours before I realized, once the diagnostic piece of code read the body content, nothing else could... so it was generating a validation error (but now for a different reason).  If anyone happened to peek at your content the same way, remember to remark it out.  You can't seek on the Body stream at least in .net core 2.2.